# Save windows forms chart control as image to the hard disk?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I draw on the chart points and lines using the chart paint event.
Then i have a button click event:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    saveFileDialog1.DefaultExt = ".txt";
    saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Text files (.txt)|*.txt";
    chart1.SaveImage(Path.GetDirectoryName(saveFileDialog1.FileName) + "\\chart.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
```

I want to save as image the chart and all the drawings i did then in another button click event or in the constructor to load back the chart with all the drawings i did so i can continue from the same place.

I tried also only:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    chart1.SaveImage(Path.GetDirectoryName(saveFileDialog1.FileName) + "\\chart.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
```

In both cases i'm getting exception when trying to save:

ArgumentException The path is not of a legal form

```
System.ArgumentException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147024809
  Message=The path is not of a legal form.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.IO.Path.NormalizePath(String path, Boolean fullCheck, Int32 maxPathLength, Boolean expandShortPaths)
       at System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(String path)
       at DietTracker.Form1.button2_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\C-Sharp\test\Form1.cs:line 334
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
       at DietTracker.Program.Main() in d:\C-Sharp\test\Program.cs:line 19
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Comment: Code is fairly bizarre.  Why would you use .txt as a filter for an image file?  Why are you not using the filename that the user provided?  Just use saveFileDialog1.FileName directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `Chart` like any other `Control` has the `DrawToBitmap` method.

```
using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(chart1.ClientSize.Width, chart1.ClientSize.Height))
{
    chart1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, chart1.ClientRectangle);
    bmp.Save("yourfilename", ImageFormat.Png);
}
```

But in addition it also has a `Chart.SaveImage` method, with a rather rich selection of [formats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chartimageformat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), including some wmf  (Windows Enhanced Metafile) formats to choose from:

```
chart1.SaveImage("yourfilename", ChartImageFormat.Png);
```

Note that both will save the current view, i.e. zoomed and scrolled.

But as you are drawing onto the `Chart`'s surface in the `Paint` event the `SaveImage` method will not work for you, as it only uses the chart data, not the things you draw in the `Paint` event.. so go for the `DrawToBitmap` version!

Note that both methods save an image of the chart, just as you have asked, not the data values!

As is noted in a comment the right way to get a filename from the user is something like this:

```
SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
// set it up..but not as text!
// then use it only if ok:
if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) bmp.Save(sfd.FileName, ImageFormat.Png);
```

Note that I chose `png` for best results, `jpg` tends to get blurry around small fonts.